# Save Arraylist of custom objects SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, set, sharedpreferences

I am really confused about how to save my ArrayList of custom objects into SharedPreference. I looked up a very popular thread but did not understand solution as certain variables were not given context. My arraylist has certain things like Strings, UUIDs, and Dates, and I do not mind going to API 11 to avoid using gson or json. If someone were to be so kind as to explain the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences) or provide their own I would really appreciate. I am new to this, been doing for a couple of months and want to make sure I understand everything in depth but my english is not so well. Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Please check this link it is help full to you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Comment: @prshntjjl I ask about the answer to that. I do not understand what type myScores is or what scoreEditor is

Answer (score 0):

Serialize that arraylist and store it in sharedPreference.

```
Profile profile = myProfile;
String serializedData = profile .serialize();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("Profile", serializedData);
editor.apply();
```

For Deserialize

```
String profileSerialized = prefs.getString("Profile", "");
profile = Profile.create(profileSerialized);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into storing the data into a [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).  SharedPreferences wasn't intended to save custom objects. If you really want to use SharedPreferences then Gson will be the best solution. API 11 added the ability to save a list of strings, not objects.

Comment: This is a possibility, do you know what is recommended method? Should I use db or gson or should I save as set and save as that like the thread I linked to recommends?

Comment: A db is recommended as it requires no dependencies.